# SQL How do I get a part of a value that is between between specific left and right value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to know what select statement can be used to get a piece of a column value that is between a specific value on the right and on the left.

Table contains the following information.

| shipment_plsid | tag | element |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1948 | INCOTERMS | INCOTERMS VER="1">TYP>4/TYP>VAR>SHIPPER/VAR>/INCOTERMS> |
| 2023 | INCOTERMS | INCOTERMS VER="1">TYP>4/TYP>VAR>DDP/VAR>/INCOTERMS> |

I need to retrieve the value for all records from column element that is between VAR> and /VAR.

Result should look like:

| element |
| --- |
| SHIPPER |
| DDP |

Thanks

Comment: You can use index search + substring, or you can use regex extraction. What's the specific database?

Comment: What is the DBMS you're using? Please add a tag with that information. Also, what did you try so far? Cheers

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySQL, this is what you need:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX('VER="1">TYP>4/TYP>VAR>SHIPPER</VAR</INCOTERMS', "</VAR", 1), "VAR>", -1);
```

For example:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX('VER="1">TYP>4/TYP>VAR>SHIPPER</VAR</INCOTERMS', "</VAR", 1), "VAR>", -1) as result;
+----------+
| result   |
|----------|
| SHIPPER  |
+----------+
1 row in set
Time: 0.011s
```

If you are using another db, please let us know which one it is

Comment: I have rephrased my question. Hope this will give a better idea of what I mean :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a `SUBSTRING` function and work out the start/length using `CHARINDEX`.
You have to add four characters to your first parameter to move start position to the end of the `VAR>` phrase. Similarly work out the length.

Here is a working solution:

```
select SUBSTRING(element,CHARINDEX('VAR>',element)+4,CHARINDEX('/VAR>',element)-CHARINDEX('VAR>',element)-4)from YourTable
```